# How sort posts by date from json

Tags: ios, sorting, swift3

Note:  Reformatted to make code more readable, had to add text here so edit would be acceptable to the system.:

My json data is :

```
[
   {
      "language": "en",
      "polarity": 10,
      "rating": "",
      "source": "Facebook",
      "text": "FortyLove Sport Centers likes a photo.",
      "time": "2013-06-02",
      "wordsCount": 6,
      "details": "http://tour-pedia.org/api/getReviewDetails?    id=53513431ae9eef9405b2f18c"

   },
   {
      "language": "en",
      "polarity": 10,
      "rating": "",
      "source": "Facebook",
      "text": "FortyLove Sport Centers likes a status.",
      "time": "2013-05-26",
      "wordsCount": 6,
      "details": "http://tour-pedia.org/api/getReviewDetails?id=53513431ae9eef9405b2f18d"
   }
]
```

And my source code is

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "http://tour-pedia.org/api/getReviews?location=Rome&category=poi")!) { (data, response , error) in
if error != nil {
    print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
}
if let resultArray = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])) as? [[String:Any]] {
        for jsonreviews in resultArray {
            let review = Review()
            review.rating = jsonreviews["rating"] as? Int ?? 0
            review.text = jsonreviews["text"] as! String
            review.time = jsonreviews["time"] as! String
            reviews.append(review)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableview.reloadData()   // if you use tableview
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

I don't have any idea how to sort by date, help me with code

Comment: Just convert to `NSDate` then use `sorted`

Comment: You don't have a date. The "time" value is a string in the form "yyyy-MM-dd". Just sort the string like you would any string. A string representing a date in the form "yyyy-MM-dd" can be sorted as a normal string and sorted values will be sorted in the correct order.

Comment: can you tell me how to call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should model your response of API call and then call the sort function on the array of your modeled data.Here is a blog on "working with json" by Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37

Here is a method as you have your data in reviews array,

```
    func sortByDate(){

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    //define your date format
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd "
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")

     reviews.sort{

        let date1  = formatter.date(from: $0.time)
        let date2 = formatter.date(from: $1.time)

        if date1 != nil && date2 != nil{
        return date1! > date2!
        }
        return false
      }

    }
```

Comment: Your date format isn't even close to correct for the data in the question.

Comment: You mean , I want to change string as nsdate , it's not working, once see my code

Comment: If you want to sort by date , you must convert your string into date object.You don't need to do it your self, in sortByDate() we are converting string into date.

Comment: @jithendra Solanki , i wonder where it can call sortbydate() in code,can you give me perfect explanation

Comment: @udaykumar I have edited the answer to match your requirement. Now call  sortByDate() just before reloading the table view as